# python unittests define a global webdriver variable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-unittest

I'd make a global setting for a webdriver browser.
So, I wrote a separate class "Settings" for all unittests, where I use either vars:

```
class Settings:
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 #driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe")
```

In my unit tests (all with the same structure) I call the driver in such way:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = Settings.driver
def test_WebDriverAuthTestIn(self):

    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(lk_url)

def test_name(self):
    some test_logic in browser

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

however, other tests failes after the first sucessful unittest run. Browser doesn't open for the next tests (winerror-10061).
It seems that other tests couldn't run driver as well

works well if I write for each test

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

instead of

```
self.driver = Settings.driver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally not best practice to define a global webdriver variable, and your code is not working because after each test, the driver is closed.  You can't re-open a driver once it has been closed, so you will need a new instance of it for your next test.

```
class Settings:
  def getDriver():
    return webdriver.Firefox()
```

and

```
def setUp(self):
  self.driver = Settings.getDriver()
def test_WebDriverAuthTestIn(self):

  driver = self.driver
  driver.get(lk_url)

def test_name(self):
  some test_logic in browser

def tearDown(self):
  self.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```